# A person who can see the past of others (or himself)

Tags: vocabulary

What do we call a person who can see the past of the others (or himself), i.e. he is some divine person and does not make false claims of knowing the past.

Comment: Please define "divine person", that will greatly help us in giving you a good answer to your question.

Comment: I have understood what I was asking. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General terms are "psychic", "fortune teller", "soothsayer", and "seer".

"Psychic" is fairly modern. It is fine if talking about someone in the past 50 year ago, but if used to talk about someone hundreds of years ago would likely sound anachronistic. "Fortune teller" is routinely used for people who tell you about your present or your past as well as for those who claim to predict the future.

There are also terms for specific methods of fortune telling. Like "astrologer" for someone who claims insights based on observing the stars, "phrenologist" for someone who studies the shape of your head, "palm reader" for someone who studies your hand, etc.

"Divine" means "having to do with God or the gods". You wouldn't normally use that word to describe a human being, even one with psychic powers. Zeus is divine. Uri Geller is not. If you want to say that someone was given his special abilities by the gods, you might say he has "divine powers".

"Divine" is also a mostly-obsolete word used to praise a woman, as in, "When Sally Jones came on stage in that beautiful gown she looked just divine."

So if you title a poem, "The Divine Lady", readers first impression would be either that she was literally a goddess, or that she was beautiful or graceful.

Note that "diviner" is different. That means someone who has magic powers to find objects. Like people who claim to be able to find water in the desert or to find treasure.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who uses rituals to [divine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divination) things about you is a *divinator* or a *diviner*

There is another word for a fortune teller: A [soothsayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune-telling) - perhaps that is better for a title, they normally tell your future, but start by attempting to tell about you

You may want to ask this at the [Writers stackexchange site](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: So, I am writing a poem about a lady who sees someone's past.I want to give the poem a title "The ___ Lady".Thus,will it be ok to write "The Divine Lady" ?

Comment: _The divining lady_ - the divine lady means she is goddesslike

Answer (score 0):

The past is "history." As a result, it is (mostly) accessible to anyone who wants to seek it out.

A person who seeks out the past (his own, or others') may be called a "dweller on bygones." (Bygones are things "gone by," in the past.)